# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sundogsoftware.spark.RatingsCounte

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I dont know what is wrong here. When I run I keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class com.sundogsoftware.spark.RatingsCounter" in my scala IDE.

this is my scala code

```
package com.sundogsoftware.spark

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._

/** Count up how many of each star rating exists in the MovieLens 100K 
data set. */
object RatingsCounter {

/** Our main function where the action happens */
def main(args: Array[String]) {

// Set the log level to only print errors
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

// Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine, named RatingsCounter
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "RatingsCounter")

// Load up each line of the ratings data into an RDD
val lines = sc.textFile("../ml-100k/u.data")

// Convert each line to a string, split it out by tabs, and extract the third field.
// (The file format is userID, movieID, rating, timestamp)
val ratings = lines.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))

// Count up how many times each value (rating) occurs
val results = ratings.countByValue()

// Sort the resulting map of (rating, count) tuples
val sortedResults = results.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)

// Print each result on its own line.
sortedResults.foreach(println)
 }
}
```

here is my project structure

[image]

Here is my run configuration

[image]

Here is my scala compiler option selected.

[image]

Trying to debug this for a few hours now, nothing seems to be working.

Any pointers will help.

Comment: How do you build and execute your artifact? Also is there a specific reason why you're using Spark 1.6?

Comment: I am trying to learn Spark scala, signed up for a course on Udemy. This is the first scala program taught in class. Trying to run it in Scala IDE. I keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class com.sundogsoftware.spark.RatingsCounter" . This is all the steps the instructor did and it worked fro him (he uses windows machine, I use MAc)

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini I had to change the vm arg in my eclipse.ini file, and for my JRE options I selected 'Use default JRE (currently 'Java SE 8 [1.8.0_172]')' when I created the scala project. That fixed this error for me.

I am using OS X, so I had to add

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

above -vmargs